# java - do json remote procedure call(RPC) from client

Tags: java, json, rpc, json-rpc

I'm working on a java application. I need to call a remote api method. Suppose I have this information: `remote_ip`, `remote_port`, `remote_method_name` and some `key-value` data to post. I need to post my data to remote server **through TCP protocol**. I tested `Sockets` in this way, but not working:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(remote_ip, remote_port);
BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
String params = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8")
      + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value1, "UTF-8");

params += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8")
+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value2, "UTF-8");
wr.write("POST " + remote_method_name + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
wr.write("Content-Length: " + params.length() + "\r\n");
wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
wr.write("\r\n");

wr.write(params);
wr.flush();
```

**Could any one tell me how can I call api method in the correct way?**

I want to do it without any third-party library if possible.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Any specific stack trace ? What is not working ?

Comment: Does not throws any exception. Just return `404 not found`. I want to know correct way to call remote api method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, even though you say you want to use raw tcp sockets, you're very clearly trying to make an HTTP rest request.   It will be **way** easier and more appropriate to use an http client for that.  I you don't want to use third-party libraries, use the built-in `HttpUrlConnection` ([example usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)).

Another advantage is that using an http client will give you a clear(er) error message.

Second, are you sure about that content-type?  If you're trying to submit json, normally the header to set would be `Content-Type: application/json`.

Third, if you're getting **404 not found**, I'd bet the url you're posting to is incorrect.  Double-check the domain and baseurl with whoever gave you the specs for this API.  Right now your URL is essentially http://remote_ip:remote_port/remote_method_name which is quite unlikely to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason is that the 'remote_method_name' you provided is wrong.
since you are making a http call, here is a brief example for you to refer.
for the page you are reading now, the request should be:

```
curl -v 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171522/java-do-json-remote-procedure-callrpc-from-client'
*   Trying 151.101.193.69...
* Connected to stackoverflow.com (151.101.193.69) port 80 (#0)
> GET /questions/40171522/java-do-json-remote-procedure-callrpc-from-client HTTP/1.1
> Host: stackoverflow.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Oct 2016 09:01:29 GMT
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Request-Guid: 405a2900-543b-4a97-8c62-8fa9019ab934
< Content-Length: 77809
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2016 09:18:59 GMT
< Via: 1.1 varnish
< Age: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Served-By: cache-ams4437-AMS
< X-Cache: MISS
< X-Cache-Hits: 0
< X-Timer: S1477041539.483029,VS0,VE95
< X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
< Set-Cookie: prov=aef7ece4-db49-60e0-3209-a2a2830d8749;         domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
......
```